# Specify makefile command target

Tags: makefile

Here's my `Makefile`

```
gitignore-create:
    touch .gitignore ;\
    echo 'node_modules' >> .gitignore ;\
    echo 'npm' >> .gitignore ;\
    echo '.DS_Store' >> .gitignore ;\
```

If I run `make gitignore-create` I get the gitignore file the current directory.

I'm looking for a way to run this makefile command from the same directory but have the target be specified to another. I'd like to not add a `cd` into the command itself though.

I tried something like this:

```
# make wrap package=my-package command=gitignore-create
wrap:
    pushd packages/$(package)/ && make -C ${CURDIR} $(command) && popd
```

And it only creates the file in the actual current dir.

Answer (score 2):

There's lots wrong with this:

```
wrap:
        pushd packages/$(package)/ && make -C ${CURDIR} $(command) && popd
```

The very first thing is you should *never* use the static command `make` when invoking recursive make rules.  *Always* use the variable `$(MAKE)` (or if you prefer, `${MAKE}`: they're identical).

Second, you can't use `pushd` and `popd` (at least not portably) because those are bash commands, but make always runs `/bin/sh` as its shell (unless you change it by setting the `SHELL` makefile variable) and on many systems, `/bin/sh` is *not* bash.

Third, you don't need to do that anyway because in UNIX/Linux, as with all right-thinking operating systems, the current directory is a property of the current process (part of its environment) and changing the current directory doesn't change the parent process's current directory.  And, every recipe line in a makefile is a whole new process (that runs a shell).  So you can use `cd` directly in any recipe line and as soon as that recipe line finishes and the shell exits, all the changes to the environment, including the current directory, will be gone: you don't have to explicitly undo them.

So you can write the rule above equivalently as:

```
wrap:
        cd packages/$(package)/ && $(MAKE) -C ${CURDIR} $(command)
```

However, ultimately this doesn't do anything because the `-C` option when given to make causes make to change it's working directory to the value you provided.  So this recipe says, "first change directories to `packages/$(package)`, then run make and tell it that the first thing it should do before it starts any commands is to change directories back to the original directory".  Clearly this is identical to just running make without changing directories at all.

Your explanation is not completely clear but what I *think* you want to do is something like this:

```
# this variable assignment must come before any include statements
myMakefile := $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
  ...
wrap:
        cd packages/$(package)/ && $(MAKE) -f $(myMakefile) $(command)
```

which first remembers the path to the current makefile, then creates a recipe which changes directory into `packages/$(package)` then runs make giving it the current makefile to parse (but not changing directories, don't use `-C`!) and the command to run.

Comment: This is giving me some errors

`cd packages/reggi/ && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Makefile gitignore-create`

`make[1]: Makefile: No such file or directory`
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `Makefile'.  Stop.
make: *** [wrap] Error 2

Comment: Here's my file. I basically want a way to have both the bottom recipes exist.

https://gist.github.com/reggi/e180f3a3b8beaabd3c37a15cb6c6c628,

Comment: Either by checking if the `package` variable exists then cd'ing or by having a wrap method that allows me to augment it there.

Comment: `mkfile_path := $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))` fixed it

Comment: Then you should probably mark this answer as accepted, so that your question no longer comes up as unresolved, and to award MadScientist some well-earned reputation points.

Comment: Oops updated to add abspath.  Somehow I thought MAKEFILE_LIST always included the absolute path.  I should have checked that.